# Invertability of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse, exterior-algebra

$\newcommand{\AA}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\Tr}[1]{\operatorname{Tr}\left[#1\right]}$
I have a problem that I suspect there is a “relatively” simple answer to but it is currently eluding me.  I am working with the expansion of a characteristic for a given matrix $\textbf{A}$.  Using the notation of exterior algebra we can show that this expansion is given by:
$$
\left\vert
  \lambda\mathbf I_{n\times n} - \mathbf A
\right\vert
= \sum_{k=0}^n \lambda^{n-k}(-1)^k \Tr{\Lambda^k \mathbf A}
=0
$$
The last term in that sum can be calculated by:
$$
\Tr{\Lambda^k \mathbf A}
=
\frac{1}{k!}
\begin{vmatrix}
\Tr{\AA} & k-1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\Tr{\AA^2} & \Tr{\AA} & k-2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\Tr{\AA^3} & \Tr{\AA^2} & \Tr{\AA} & k-3 & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  & \vdots \\
\Tr{\AA^{k-1}} & \Tr{\AA^{k-2}} & \Tr{\AA^{k-3}} & \ldots & \Tr{\AA} & 1 \\
\Tr{\AA^k} & \Tr{\AA^{k-1}} & \Tr{\AA^{k-2}} & \Tr{\AA^{k-3}} & \ldots & \Tr{\AA}
\end{vmatrix}
= \frac{\det |\mathbf Q_k|}{k!}$$
where $\mathbf Q_k$ is the matrix inside of the determinant.  For some work I am doing I would like to put a condition on the invertability of $\mathbf Q_k$ as a function of $\Tr{\AA}$ and $k$ but unfortunately I cannot figure anything out.  Just to note, matrix $\AA$ is $n\times n$ and $1\leq k \leq n$.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could use to determine this?  I have tried to calculate the determinant and the smallest eigenvalue/singular value but things just get really messy very quickly.

Comment: Must you use this expansion?  Why not find the matrix for $\bigwedge^k A$ instead?

Comment: I admittedly do not have any experience with exterior algebra outside of what I have discussed here.  I happened to stumble upon this form while considering some other methods and found that it fit my form perfectly, so I have not considered finding $\bigwedge^k A$ but it is something I will try to look into.  Thanks for the response @Muphrid